# Bash script date error

Tags: linux, bash, date

i'm trying to get an old date in a bash script, but it throws this error

```
"./bkc.sh: line 10: 20130122: command not found"
```

It's like tries to use the result date as a function instead of assign the value to the OLDATE var.

Here's my code:

```
OLDATE= `date -d '7 days ago' +'%Y%m%d'`
```

Can anyone help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the space between OLDATE and the command.

Bash doesn't want spaces in assigning values

Comment: Thanks! What a rookie mistake!